# indexing a vector with a logical vector without changing length

Tags: r

i need to find duplicate column entries within a row. i have a logical vector for that is true when the columns arent duplicate in that row and false when they are. i want to use this logical vector to remove the entries that are duplicate but when i do this var2[logical vector] the length changes as only the values for true are kept and the rows with false are removed, i however want these to be kept and just be na or empty. is this possible?

so for

```
1 a b
2 a b
3 a a
4 a a
5 a b
```

i have the logical vector `[TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE]`

and i want to use this frame and this vector to get

```
1 a b
2 a b
3 a
4 a
5 a b
```

or

```
1 a b
2 a b
3 a NA
4 a NA
5 a b
```

is this possible?

Comment: Subset-assign `NA`?

Comment: e.g., `DF[!logical_vector, 2] <- NA`

Comment: Or `is.na(DF[[2]]) <- !logical_vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_when` from `dplyr` solves your problem without explictely specifying the logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), 
                col2 = c("b", "b", "a", "a", "b"), 
                stringsAsFactors = F)
df %>% 
  mutate(col2 = case_when(col1 == col2 ~ NA_character_,
                          col1 != col2 ~ col2))

  col1 col2
1    a    b
2    a    b
3    a <NA>
4    a <NA>
5    a    b
```